# Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error : Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=2003332927

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Using Xcode 14.3, trying to update an older swift app, once recording a voice, it is then saved to play the required effect, however, app crashes as soon as I try to play it.

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=2003332927 "(null)" UserInfo={failed call=AudioConverterSetProperty(converter, kAudioConverterEncodeBitRate, sizeof(UInt32), &bitRate)}
```

Crashes on the first line of this

```
func saveVoiceCganger() {
        do{
            
            let newAudio:AVAudioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: getOutPutUrl(), settings:  [
                AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(value:kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.low.rawValue,
                AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
                ])
            let length = self.audioFile?.length
            self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)) {
                (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
                
                
                print(newAudio.length)
                print("=====================")
                print(length!)
                print("**************************")
                
                if (newAudio.length) < length! {//Let us know when to stop saving the file, otherwise saving infinitely
                    
                    do{
                        //print(buffer)
                        try newAudio.write(from: buffer)
                    }catch _{
                        print("Problem Writing Buffer")
                    }
                }else{
                    self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                }
                
            }
        }catch _{
            print("Problem")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `try !`. That says "crash if this doesn't work". Use `do/try/catch` and then you can print the error that is thrown and see what is going wrong.

Comment: @Paulw11 is this simply a case of replacing `try!` with `catch` ? I am coming from an `obj-c` background so still learning `Swift`.

Comment: You should start with `do { try ... } catch { print(error) }` to at least see what error you have.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, replacing `try!` with `try` the code no longer crashes and functions correctly, how strange!?

Comment: @DannyRoy Why is it strange? `try!` means crash me. `try` doesn't. The computer is just doing what you told it to do.

Comment: @matt As you know, the difference between `try!` and `try` is how failure is handled. The OP states that simply changing `try!` to `try` stopped it from failing. That is strange. If it failed with `try!` then why doesn't it fail with `try`? I would have expected the change from `try!` to `try` to have been a change from a crash to a catch, not from crash to working just fine.

Comment: @HangarRash AVFoundation uses exceptions oddly. Swift interacts poorly with its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In general, think of the `!` as the crash operator, and don't use it. In this context, it means try calling some function that throws, and crash if it throws.

Change `try!` to `try`, and then in your catch, log the error. (don't use `catch _` and ignore the result.)

In other contexts, `!` is a force-unwrap, which is the "crash if nil` operator. It can also be used as to create "implicitly unwrapped optionals", which set up a crash any time you reference such an optional and it's nil.

(The `!` operator can also be logical NOT. That use doesn't cause crashes.)