# Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer)

Tags: swift, cloudkit, swift-data

I am using SwiftData in combination with iCloud for a private project to store and synchronize credentials. Since I have different models, I need a common container for `UntisConfiguration` and `ElternportalCredentials`.

Since I renamed the model from `ElternpotalLoginModel` to `ElternportalCredentials`, the app always crashes on my real iPhone with the following error:

`MyApp/ParentPortalCredentialsDataSource.swift:21: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer)`

```
@Model
final class ElternportalCredentials {

    var mail: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    
    init(elternportalMail: String = "", elternportalPassword: String = "") {
        self.mail = elternportalMail
        self.password = elternportalPassword
    }
    
}
```

```
final class ElternportalCredentialsDataSource {
    private let modelContainer: ModelContainer
    private let modelContext: ModelContext

    @MainActor
    static let shared = ElternportalCredentialsDataSource()

    @MainActor
    private init() {
        let config = ModelConfiguration(groupContainer: .identifier("com.company.myapp"))
        self.modelContainer = try! ModelContainer(for: ElternportalCredentials.self, UntisConfiguration.self, configurations: config)
        self.modelContext = modelContainer.mainContext
    }

    func saveCredentials(credentials: ElternportalCredentials) {
        modelContext.insert(credentials)
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func fetchCredentials() -> [ElternportalCredentials] {
        do {
            return try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<ElternportalCredentials>())
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func removeOldCredentials() {
        let credentials = fetchCredentials()
        
        for credential in credentials {
            modelContext.delete(credential)
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely, this does not happen when I start the app in a newly created simulator. Unfortunately, I cannot test whether the error also occurs on a new physical device on which no previous version of the app was installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error : Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=2003332927](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76322263/fatal-error-try-expression-unexpectedly-raised-an-error-error-domain-com-a)

Comment: **Don't use `try!`** [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76322263/fatal-error-try-expression-unexpectedly-raised-an-error-error-domain-com-a?rq=2)

Comment: "Since I renamed the container...",  I assume you mean model and not container. Did you create a migration for this renaming?

Comment: Yes, I mean model. I did not create a migration.

Comment: I am aware that forcing something is bad practice and I usually don't do it. But since I don't wont `modelContainer` and `modelContext` to be optionals, I decided to do it this way.

Comment: I f you didn't do a migration then how can the app (ModelContainer more precisely) know that you have renamed the model? I believe you need to research how to do a migration, specially when iCloud is involved.

Comment: Is there a way to just reset the local  swift data configuration on my physically device? This way I could simply create a new cloudkit container using the new model configuration.

Comment: If you remove the SQLite database file completely then the app will create a new one the next time it’s started. That being said I have no idea if that could cause any issues with iCloud since I haven’t used it much.

Comment: Okay, where is the SQLite database file located?

Comment: I mostly develop for macOS and not iOS so you need to do some research yourself because I am not sure where it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257051/discussion-between-multimedia-and-joakim-danielson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue by doing the following:

1. Navigate to [App Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list) > MyApp > AppGroups.
2. Add an App Group as shown below:
   [image: Add App Group on Apple Developer page]
3. Go to the capabilities in your Xcode project and configure the container. [image: App Group Capabilities]

It should look like this:

[image: New App Group]

4. Finally, use the newly created container in your code:

```
    let config = ModelConfiguration(groupContainer: .identifier("group.com.company.MyApp"))
```